# How to add php.ini to a configmap in kubernetes yaml

Tags: php, kubernetes, yaml, dockerhub, configmap

Hello I am new to kubernetes. I am currently stuck trying to use a docker image from dockerhub were it is a php-fpm image. I would like to be able to customize the php.ini in a configmap how would I go about doing that. The image on dockerhub is 
[crunchgeek/php-fpm](https://hub.docker.com/r/crunchgeek/php-fpm)  and the instructions for php.ini say there is a environment variable  "PHP_INI_PATH=/path/to/php.ini
will include specified php.ini configuration during php-fpm manager start. It allows to use a wildcard in case you would like to include several .ini configuration files."  How can I add a environment variable that controls the php.ini file to a configmap in kubernetes  please a yaml example would help me so much thanks.

Comment: do you want to add the ini as file or key-value?

Comment: @MickeyHovel I would like to add it as a file. Also i should have mentioned but I am not using helm

Comment: ok, I'll update my answer by just adding a 1 liner command in order to create the config map from file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case you want to mount a configuration file of PHP .ini (creating a configmap from file) to your pod can do the following depends on if you're using helm or not.

When using helm you need to create a config map YAML file and put the desired configuration file (php.ini in your scenario) under a dedicated folder, (e.g **conf** folder) in the root of your helm Chart location, and then create a config map from that file and mount it to the deployment accordingly to your needs.

In case you are not using helm you can create the config map from a file directly using a kubectl command (took from this reference [config map from file command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files)):

**create a config map from file with no helm:**

```
kubectl create configmap phpini-configmap --from-file=configure-pod-container/configmap/php.ini
```

**config map YAML when using helm would look similar to:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: phpini-configmap
data:
  php.ini: |-
{{ .Files.Get "conf/php.ini" | indent 4 }}
```

The pod should then consume this config map and mount it to the right path

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    - name: php-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "cat /etc/config/php.ini" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: ini-configmap
        mountPath: /etc/config/php.ini
        subPath: php.ini
      env:
      - name: PHP_INI_PATH
        value: /etc/config/php.ini
  volumes:
    - name: ini-configmap
      configMap:
        name: phpini-configmap
```

Answer (score 4):

First you'll need to define the ConfigMap representing your `php.ini`, something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: php-ini-config
  namespace: default
data:
  php.ini: |
    foo=bar
    one=two
```

Then you can [render this configmap into your workload as a volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap), which looks something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "cat /etc/config/php.ini" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
      env:
      - name: PHP_INI_PATH
        value: /etc/config/php.ini
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: php-ini-config
```

Notice in this YAML we also include the `PHP_INI_PATH` environment variable pointing to the file under the volume, `/etc/config/php.ini`.